# After clicking the "right" Button, the app stop

Tags: android, android-activity

I start a Activity (via Intent, and I give it putExtra(String): RED, YELLOW, GREEN or BLUE)

currentColor has the color that I don't wan't to be clicked.

I have 4 Buttons (I deleted it from source, because I dont think you need it).

```
public class ColorChooser extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
String currentColor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Choose a color");
    setContentView(R.layout.color_chooser);
    setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

    currentColor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CurrentColor");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    String picked = "";

    boolean ok = true;
    while(ok) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnRed:
                picked = "RED";
                break;
            case R.id.btnYellow:
                picked = "YELLOW";
                break;
            case R.id.btnGreen:
                picked = "GREEN";
                break;
            case R.id.btnBlue:
                picked = "BLUE";
                break;
        }
        if(picked.equals(currentColor)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose other color please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else {
            returnIntent.putExtra("Color", picked);
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

}

In my Manifest I have this. So it shows like a Dialog. I have to choose a color.

```
<activity
            android:name=".ColorChooser"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            />
```

**My question now is: If I pick a color thats != currentColor, its fine. But if I pick the same color as currentColor, the app stops. The Button in the app is shown as clicked (yellow).
I think it because I used while. I dont know how I can do this, that I should pick a color, until it is != currentColor**

```
05-21 18:33:09.782    1873-1873/com.example.thm_wip1.uno E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.example.thm_wip1.uno.Deck.<init>(Deck.java:25)
            at com.example.thm_wip1.uno.MultiplayerActivity.onCreate(MultiplayerActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.thm_wip1.uno.CardValue.<clinit>(CardValue.java:13)
            at com.example.thm_wip1.uno.Deck.<init>(Deck.java:25)
            at com.example.thm_wip1.uno.MultiplayerActivity.onCreate(MultiplayerActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hmm. But if it is the same color, I should choose a new color until it is != currentColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your onClick Like Below. Remove while loop from your onClick method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    String picked = "";

    switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnRed:
                picked = "RED";
                break;
            case R.id.btnYellow:
                picked = "YELLOW";
                break;
            case R.id.btnGreen:
                picked = "GREEN";
                break;
            case R.id.btnBlue:
                picked = "BLUE";
                break;
    }
    if(picked.equals(currentColor)){
           //If picked color is same as currentColor do nothig
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose other color please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } else {
       //return pikced color
        returnIntent.putExtra("Color", picked);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Serg Woron Please Also Check the line number 52 : MultiplayerActivity.onCreate(MultiplayerActivity.java:52). It throws null pointer exception.